# how to fill NaN value in one column by looking at other column

Tags: pandas, data-analysis

I want to fill `NaN` values in `Gender` column by looking at the name of the person (which is given in another column). So far, I have extracted boys name which have `NaNs` and made a list of those names:

```
boys_names = ['Robin Ounc', 'Chris Stew', 'Neil Bhor', ... and so on]
```

I want to fill those `NaN` values in `df['Gender']` column with `'M'` if their name is present in that `boys_list`. And with `'F'` if their name is not present. I have tried `If-Else` statement but I failed. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
#boys_names = ['Robin Ounc', 'Chris Stew', 'Neil Bhor', ... and so on]
df.loc[df['Gender'].isnull(), 'Gender'] = df.loc[df['Gender'].isnull(), 'name'].map(
    lambda x: 'M' if x in boys_names else 'F'
    )
```

Some notes:

- use `.loc` to pick the "name" which are NaN in 'Gender' (use `pd.Series.isnull()`)
- `pd.Series.map` accept a function with each data in series as input and return each data with some changes that your function made. (here just check whether `name` in `boys_name` or not)
- use `.loc` to assign back to the"name" which are NaN in 'Gender'

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a good approach:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": ["Jhon", "Robin Ounc", "Maria", "Alex"],
        "Gender": ["M", None, "F", None]
    }
)
boys_names = ['Robin Ounc', 'Chris Stew', 'Neil Bhor']
df["Gender"].fillna(df["Name"].isin(boys_names).map({True: "M", False: "F"}))
```

I've just used a `map` function as a `if-else` after `isin` in order to validate if `Name` is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSaAw.png) using *np.select()*